# Show sql records which is 30 days older than added date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you please guide to make query of sql server,
I want to fetch records once it reach to date2 and it should stop showing after 30 days from date which is added in date1. 
Kindly find below my current query,

```
select distinct Convert(nvarchar(50), a.no) ,name ,name2 ,'test' ,date1 ,'Pending' 
from table1 a 
full outer join dbo.table2 g on g.no = a.no 
where date2 < = '2017-05-027 00:00:00.000'
```

Current

```
Date1        Name1        Name2      Date2(reminder date)
25/05/2017  Raviraj     Jadhav       27/05/2017
```

Expected (Now after 30 days, records should not visible)

```
Date1        Name1        Name2      Date2(reminder date)
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks Carlos... assume that I want to remind after 2 days which was added yesterday in database. Now it should show records after 2 days whenever we run this query, which is working fine with this query. But now i want to stop this showing after 30 days from added date.

Comment: Show me some data and expected output. I cant understand what your are saying.

Comment: Current ( we have set reminder for 29/05/2017.). 
Date1   Name  name2   date2                                                                          27/05/2017 Raviraj jadhav  29/05/2017                                                                                                                                                                                                 Expected (Now it should not show records after 30 days)                                                                                                    
Date1  Name  name2  date2

Comment: Edit your question with the example.

Comment: Hey Carlos... Thanks... I have edited question with example...

Comment: Your example `Date1` is equal to `Date2` ? Where you get/count the 30 days?

Comment: Ohh, apologies.. My date1 is 25/05/2017 and Date2 is 27/05/2017... Thanks Carlos..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct Convert(nvarchar(50), a.no) ,name ,name2 ,'test' ,date1 ,'Pending' 
from table1 a 
full outer join 
dbo.table2 g 
on g.no = a.no 
where date2 >= '2017-05-27 00:00:00.000' and datediff(dd,date1,getdate())<= 30
```

The query will return results after date2 as well as stop resulting the same once when date1 and current date differennce is greater than 30 days.

Comment: Thanks @JayaPrakash, This query resolved my issue. Thank you so much......

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM  table1 a 
  full outer join dbo.table2 g on g.no = a.no 
  WHERE date2 > DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks @carlos.. With this query, I am getting records which is added in last 30 days. But i want to stop showing records which 30 days older than date2.. Thanks in advance....

Comment: How many times should I tell you. Provide examples. Read the links I provide you so learn how make a good question.